# Dropbox AD Connector - Reset Password

Tags: dropbox-api

I am using Dropbox AD Connector to sync changes from Active Directory to Dropbox Business Account.

Recently I tried changing the password of one of our users, but same is not getting reflected on the Dropbox Business Account.

The User still able to log-in using the old password.

Please let me know, if the reset password feature is supported through Dropbox AD Connector or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Dropbox AD Connector does not support resetting or changing passwords.